# How do I force glue into a hard to reach hollow?

Tags: glue

I have a group of wall tiles coming off the wall. They don't separate from each other, just come off together - when I knock with a finger I hear dull sound meaning there's already a hollow behind the tiles and I also see that the top row clearly comes off the wall.

Normally I would separate the tiles, clean them, reattach them to the wall and seal the seams, but that's more work than I'd like to do right now. I'd rather try to glue them onto the wall without separating. I picked holes in the seams and I plan to inject PVA glue behind the tiles and then press the whole group of tiles onto the wall (I'll put a wide board and insert a bar between the board and the opposite wall).

The question is how do I inject glue behind the tiles? The holes I picked are something like two millimeters in diameter. I thought of using a medical syringe, but I guess its needle has a too small hole and glue is not just flixible enough to be forced through such small holes. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A syringe IS the best tool for such a job. Just make sure it has a nozzle/needle suitable to the adhesive used. They come in many different sizes. For large sizes you may want to locate veterinary supplies. Perhaps even talk to the local vet, who may be prepared to sell you a couple.

As for the PVA, it is generally not a good choice for tiles, especially if the tiles are in a wet area, although I can't think of anything more suitable for squeezing into such a small opening.

Answer (score 7):

Check in at your local dollar store and look for a turkey injector kit. This is a large syringe used to inject broth into a bird for cooking.  The opening at he end is pretty large and may pass glue easily and deep.  Also, they are cheap, just a buck or two.

Comment: Plus you don't have to be suspected of drug use.